# Google Script replacing Index/Match - Matching Values Only

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to modify a function, essentially i need to replicate index/match but with a script.

I'm using some code that works almost perfectly for me, the values that match are updated fine but unfortunately the values on the 'Slave' sheet that do not match the 'Master' sheet are overwritten with null

**MASTER SHEET**

| VESSEL | C/O DATES | WHARF | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ROLLING | ROLLING |  | 86 |
| SPARE | SPARE |  | 0 |
| TBA | TBA |  | 7 |
| AITOLIKOS 004N | ETD 17.11 | DPWORLD | 0 |
| ARKADIA 2210N | C/O 07.11 @ 1200 | TBA | 2 |
| ASL BAUHINIA 2201N | ETD 07.11 | DPWORLD | 16 |
| CMA CGM BELLINI 216N | ETD 20.11 | DPWORLD | 1 |
| CMA CGM MARLIN 752N | TBA |  | 0 |
| CMA CGM MOLIERE 242N | C/O 04.11 @ 1100 | DPWORLD | 0 |
| CONTI CONQUEST 239N | C/O 03.11 @ 2300 | PATRICKS | 13 |
| COSCO ADEN 106N | C/O 03.11 @ 1900 | DPWORLD | 90 |
| COSCO FELIXSTOWE 177N | C/O 08.11 @ 2200 | TBA | 12 |

**SLAVE SHEET**

| FULL OR EMPTY | TRAILER TYPE | CUSTOMER DETAILS | TRUCK # | RELEASE NUMBER | Vessel | Cut Off |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| EMPTY DELIVERY | SIDELOADER | CH&S | On HOLD refer Adam | 35803252DA | TBA | TBA |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| EMPTY DELIVERY | TRAILER | CH&S |  | TWMBA270922 | CMA CGM BELLINI 216N | ETD 20.11 |
| EMPTY DELIVERY | TRAILER | CH&S |  | TWMBA270922 | CMA CGM BELLINI 216N | ETD 20.11 |
| EMPTY DELIVERY | TRAILER | CH&S |  | TWMBA270922 | COSCO ADEN 106N | C/O 03.11 @ 1900 |
| EMPTY DELIVERY | TRAILER | CH&S |  | TWMBA270922 | COSCO ADEN 106N | C/O 03.11 @ 1900 |
| EMPTY DELIVERY | TRAILER | CH&S |  | TWMBA270922 | COSCO ADEN 106N | C/O 03.11 @ 1900 |
| EMPTY DELIVERY | TRAILER | CH&S |  | TWMBA270922 | COSCO ADEN 106N | C/O 03.11 @ 1900 |

## **Code:**

Original Author of the following code: TheMaster

```js
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

function cutoffUpdater (
  fromSht = ss.getSheetByName('MASTER'),
  toSht = ss.getSheetByName('SLAVE'),
  fromCompCol = 1,
  toCompCol = 6,
  fromCol = 2,
  toCol = 7
) {
  const toShtLr = toSht.getLastRow();
  const toCompArr = toSht.getRange(2, toCompCol, toShtLr - 1, 1).getValues();
  const fromArr = fromSht.getDataRange().getValues();
  fromCompCol--;
  fromCol--;

  /*Create a hash object of fromSheet*/

  const obj1 = fromArr.reduce((obj, row) => {
    let el = row[fromCompCol];
    el in obj ? null : (obj[el] = row[fromCol]);
    return obj;
  }, {});


   //Paste to column
  toSht.getRange(2, toCol, toShtLr - 1, 1)
    .setValues(toCompArr.map(row => (
        row[0] in obj1 ? [obj1[row[0]]] : [null]
    ))
  );
}
```

## **What i Require**

In my situation, i need any value on the 'slave' sheet that doesn't match or is not present on the 'Master' sheet to remain untouched.

I have spent 2 days trying to modify the code but to be honest, the "hash object" is above my abilities.

Follow-up question from:
[Google Script version of VLookup (More Efficient Method?)](https://www.stackoverflow.com/60255775)

Comment: If you're using someone else's work without giving them credit, that constitutes plagiarism, which is not welcome on Stack Exchange. To fix it, [edit] to make sure you do **ALL** the following: 1.Include a [link](/editing-help#links) to the source, 2. Mention the author's name, and 3. [Quote](/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) the copied content. For more details, see [referencing help](/help/referencing) and [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077/343832).

Answer (score 0):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
toSht.getRange(2, toCol, toShtLr - 1, 1)
  .setValues(toCompArr.map(row => (
      row[0] in obj1 ? [obj1[row[0]]] : [null]
  ))
);
```

#### To:

```
toSht.getRange(2, toCol, toShtLr - 1, 1)
  .setValues(toCompArr.map(row => (
      row[0] in obj1 ? [obj1[row[0]]] : [row[0]] // Modified
  ))
);
```

- When this modified script is run, when `row[0] in obj1` is `false`, `[row[0]]` is used. By this, the original value of "SLAVE" sheet is kept.

Comment: Tanaike - I made the modification you suggested, Non matching items in the the "Slave" Sheet no longer are written as null, but now Col 1 of the "Master" are overwritten in Col 7 of the "Slave"

Comment: @bonecyclone Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `but now Col 1 of the "Master" are overwritten in Col 7 of the "Slave"`. In this case, can you add a table of your expected situation using your 2 tables? By this, I would like to modify your script.

Comment: @bonecyclone About `but now Col 1 of the "Master" are overwritten in Col 7 of the "Slave"`, in your showing script, "MASTER" sheet is not updated, while "SLAVE" sheet is updated. So, I cannot understand it. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?